# Can reinforcement learning be used for a complete coverage navigation application?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I have a complete coverage of a 3D space problem. Most complete coverage navigation solutions use different algorithms to give the most appropriate path that covers the area, however I wish to use previous navigation data to learn the best path that covers similar areas. I thought of using reinforcement learning where the transition matrix can be obtained from the data. However, most applications in RL are formulated in manner where a goal needs to be reached. Does it mean the RL is not suitable for this sort of problems, unless the reward of being in each states can be changed once the state has been visited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RL problems roughly fall into 3 categories:

1. Finite-horizon problems, where a final state is reached.
2. Discounted problems, where the total reward is bounded in the limit.
3. Average cost per stage problems, where the average reward is bounded.

But RL is typically online learning. To learn from previous navigation data, you can use [dynamic programming methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process#Algorithms).

Comment: So I can use MDP with the transition function at hand and define different reward functions based on the status of the state (visited or not)?